# Get user email programmatically if I have user guid? (SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint

Currently I have a method to get all the users in a site collection and databind this to a dropdown.

```
private void getUsers()
{
    SPGroupCollection collGroups = SPContext.Current.Web.Groups;


    foreach (SPGroup oGroup in collGroups)
    {
        foreach (SPUser oUser in oGroup.Users)
        {
            ddlSiteOwner.Items.Add(new ListItem(oUser.Name, oUser.ID.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get users based on their guid?
I select a user in the dropdown with guid as value and I would like to use this to search for the users email.

I tried something like

```
private string getUserEmail(string userGuid)
{
    string userEmail = null;
    SPGroupCollection collGroups = SPContext.Current.Web.Groups;

    foreach (SPGroup oGroup in collGroups)
    {
        foreach (SPUser oUser in oGroup.Users.GetByID(userGuid))
        {
            userEmail = oUser.Email;
        }
    }
    return userEmail;
}
```

But with GetByID it wants 32bit integer and not a guid so how would I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: saw that users don't have guids but sids now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPUser.ID property you are using in your dropdown is an integer, not a guid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.id.aspx

So the GetByID should work normally, just parse the value as an integer.

int.Parse(), or int.TryParse()